# How to detect color live using camera on android in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, android-camera, vuforia, color-detection

i want to make a live color detection using camera on android in unity. apps that i want is like "color grab" on *playstore*.
anyone can help me how it works? or how to make it on unity?

Comment: Isn't it a simple matter of getting camera output as an image and going through every pixel in it?

Comment: @BarsiktheCat or maybe just the middle one or something, but yeah that's the way to do it.

Comment: @Hristo I meant that a lot of languages provide that feature - Xamarin and Java have bitmap, but I'm not sure about unity

Comment: is that mean unity doesn't support about color detection?

Answer (score 1):

Well SO isn't a script providing service: always try to provide what you have tried already before asking a question. If you don't have any script, at least expose you way you want to do it, the steps you think are needed, ...

Anyway, I'd advise you to take a look at Unity [`Texture2D.ReadPixels()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html) method:

- display what you need on screen
- when the user touch a place, call for `ReadPixels()`
- then retrieve the color of the desire location on the texture using [`Texture2D.GetPixel()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html)

If you want to search for a larger area (not a single pixel), you can look for all the pixels around the wanted location and then get the average color found.

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: sorry before, because i didn't know anything about live color detection. but i want to make a project like "ar coloring page" and i want to add some feature on it. i want to detect what color that user use on a paper or on 3d object and and show it on a text. ex: user use black color, so i will show what color that he use. "black", not hexa color. sorry for bad english.